# Please help me identify this plant growing over the fence

Tags: identification, weed-control, hedge

I had this hedge cut back 2 months ago, but it is growing back really fast.

Do you know what it is?
And how I can remove/control it?

EDIT: this is in the Cotswolds, UK.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's....vigorous...

Comment: For reference, here's the same hedge roughly 6 weeks ago: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/62094/6806 and location is somewhere in the UK, evidently.

Comment: That's my hedge! The same hedge as above. That was taken just after it was cut back. Since then this weed/plant has grown through the hedge. I thought I should know what it is before I plan how to deal with it.